# Two closes below EMA...?

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to tell pine script

// If I get two closes below the ema10, then close trade.

This is part of my code -

```
ema             = ta.ema(close, 10)

//Buy and Sell conditions
var float buyPrice = 0
buyCondition= close > ema and strategy.position_size == 0 and f_dateFilter

twoLowerCloses   = (close [2] < close [3] and close[1] <      close[2]) and (close < close[1])

sellCondition = (twoLowerCloses and (close<ema) and  strategy.position_size > 0)
```

It seems sometimes it's waiting for 3 closes to close the position.
I would also like it to just close the trade if there are 2 closes in a row below the ema10 - doesn't matter if they are down closes or up closes, just as long as there is 2 closes below that ema10 in a row

Have searched on here but can't find anything, tried for ages now with all sorts to no avail.

Thanks

[3 closes in a row below and still not closed?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeAMu.png)

[2 closes below but *not* closed ??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5TRh.png)

Comment: Your error message does not come from the piece of code you shared. Please share your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

```
twoLowerCloses = (close [2] < close [3] and close[1] < close[2]) and (close < close[1])
```

Here you are comparing `close` prices with previous `close` price.

You should compare them with the previous `ema` values.

```
two_consecutive_close = (close < ema) and (close[1] < ema[1])
```